# Stratification of System Fω

Tags: type-theory, type-systems, typed-lambda-calculus

I'm wondering if there's any update on [this conjecture](http://tlca.di.unito.it/opltlca/opltlcasu19.html#x24-34000) listed by Urzyczyn from years and years ago (I don't think that's its first appearance), which I'll restate below.

System F<sub>ω</sub> can be stratified into an infinite hierarchy of Systems F<sub>n</sub>, where F<sub>0</sub> corresponds to the usual polymorphic System F (quantifying over kinds ∗), F<sub>1</sub> to System F with type operators (quantifying over kinds e.g. ∗ → ∗), F<sub>2</sub> additionally quantifying over kinds e.g. (∗ → ∗) → ∗ ("to the left of 2 arrows", so to speak), and so on.

Giannini et al. (1988) [1] show that there exists a (Curry-style, unannotated) lambda term that cannot be assigned a System F type, but which can be assigned a System F<sub>1</sub> type. (I believe it's `(λxy. y(xI)(xK))Ω`, where `Ω` is assigned some type that looks like `∀a: ∗ → ∗ . τ`.)

The question is then: **For every n, is it possible to find a term that is not typeable in System F<sub>n</sub> but is typeable in System F<sub>n+1</sub> (or higher)?** Urzyczyn asked this in [an email](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Esweirich/types/archive/1991/msg00054.html) in 1991; according to [another email](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/types/archives/1993/msg00026.html) in 1993, Giannini et al. (1993) [2] were working on a partial result to collapse the hierarchy down to F<sub>1</sub> (which they call F<sub>3</sub>; unfortunate disagreement on the numbering conventions here...). Malecki (1997) shows that it does collapse (i.e. the answer to the above is *no*), but according to Urzyczyn on his webpage (first link above) the proof is incorrect.

Has any more progress been made toward this problem in either direction?

---

[1] *Characterization of typings in polymorphic type discipline*, LiCS 1988. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5101

[2] *Type inference: some results, some problems*, Fundamenta Informaticae, 19:1-2. https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.5555/175469.175472

[3] *Proofs in system F<sub>ω</sub> can be done in system F<sup>1</sup><sub>ω</sub>*, CSL 1996. https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-63172-0_46

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what prompted your interest in this question? The only person I've personally met that was enthusiastic about this was Pawel himself. It'd be cool to see renewed interest!

Comment: I think I literally just stumbled across the top link above last year while looking for unrelated stuff about rank-n polymorphism lol. It's been at the back of my mind since then bc it felt like the kind of thing that should've been (dis)proven by now, but I don't have much use for it and I'm guessing others don't either...

Comment: It certainly isn't useful in the way one might immediately think: the fact that a function is typeable in $F_1$ doesn't really guarantee that you'll have the type you "need", e.g. to apply to arguments. (What made me realize this is the fact that *every* normal form is typable in system $F$, but of course the type is usually useless).

Comment: Still, it's a natural question, and getting updates on the state of it would be nice.